# Mobile website in HTML5 not pulling CSS file until refreshed

Tags: css, html, forms, contacts

[image]I'm building a contact form for a mobile website in HTML5 and CSS. It is the same form I use on all mobile website and after not working for 5 hours I pulled the code straight from a working site I built and it still doesn't work properly.

The issue is when you go to the contact page it shows the contact form, but with the labels centered and the submit button image isn't showing up. I must refresh for it to bring up the correct CSS file to align the text left and show the submit button. Initially I thought it was from a CSS/JS conflict with my menu at the top so I pulled that and it still causes the same problem. I have cleared the cashe on my phone and web browsers and they all work the same.

Here is the link: www.lpokc.org/mobi/contact.php after going to this page hit refresh and you will see the difference.

My question is, is this a caching issue, is it server side issue, or is it a conflict in my coding. I'm not good with posting the code on this site but if you go to the mobile site from your web browser you can just right click and view source to see my code. I have a boiler plate html core file with boiler plate CSS and custom CSS.

Is there some sort of script I could use to make this page auto refresh one time on page load then not again after the reload? I don't want to use an improper fix like this but I have been working on this issue for a day.

The left side is before refresh. I have pulled the code from the site now but I think it was a js conflict because it was auto loading the css from the menu when the link for any page was clicked.

Comment: I checked it on my phone and my desktop. There doesn't seem to be a difference. Can you show a before and after of the refresh that "fixes" the css?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing it fine on my end. Seems to work flawlessly, but if you are still having a problem, you could either use cookie or session variables. If the variable does not exist, you can use the php function `header( 'Location: http://www.lpokc.org/mobi/contact.php' ) ;` to "refresh" the page. It's actually just a redirect command, but if you are sending them back to the page they are on, it is pretty much the same thing as a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It was a conflicting issue with my menu JS/CSS. I pulled it and now everything works fine.